# Assign the global variable to object after assigning value in function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

There is global variable with some default value,but that is reassigned in some function. There is object which is to be assigned the updated global variable value.

Tried function returning value and also putting the object inside the function,both things did not worked.The challenge faced is function in javascript run later after all object and variables are assigned value

```
//variable declaration(myObservable )
var myObservable = ko.observable('66');

//function definition
self.PortfolioPerformance_getval = function () {
  $.getJSON("/oracle-html-final/web/js/model/portfolioPerformance.json").then(function (deals) {

    var tempCols = [];
    var tempCols1 = [];
    for(var property in deals.item[0]) {
      self.portmax(parseInt(deals.item[0].target));

      self.myObservable = ko.observable(self.portmax());
      alert('jj'+myObservable());
      target_textval = parseInt(deals.item[0].target);
      console.log('dddd'+target_textval);
      self.portfolioPerformance_Value(parseInt(deals.item[0].portfolio_per_val));
      console.log("jinn"+deals.item[0].portfolio_per_val);
      self.h_val(deals.item[0].net_profit);
      // self.portfolioPerformance_Target = ko.observable({text: 'Target: '+ this.a});

    }

  }).fail(function(req, status, error) { alert('getJSON failed: ' + status); })

}
self.PortfolioPerformance_getval();  

//object where the value is to be reassigned
self.portfolioPerformance_Target = ko.observable({

  text: 'Target: '+ myObservable(),
  "textType": "number",
  style: {
    color: '#666666',
    fontSize: '14px'
  },
  rendered: 'on',
  /*  converter: converterFactory.createConverter({
          style: 'currency',
          currency: 'USD'
        })*/
});
```

Comment: `var myObservable` and `self.myObservable` point to two different variables. Are they supposed to be the same one?

Comment: yes,it needs to be same @JasonSpake